# Calculation for input array in every row Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new into JQuery, My code is only working for the first row, it doesn't calculate for other rows. I have two button, one for adding another row and one for deleting it. What I try to do it to calculate price+vat*quantity and put it in total field in every row.
here if the code for my html

```
<table border='1' id="mytable" dir="rtl" style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> partnumber </th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>price </th>
            <th>vat</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th> price + vat</th>
            <th> total quantity*(price+vat) </th>
            <th> </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='tr_input'>
            <td><input type='text' name="partnumber[]" class='username' id='partnumber_1' placeholder='پارت نه‌مبه‌ر '></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='name' name="name[]" id='name_1' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='price' name="price[]" id='price_1' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='vat' name="vat[]" id='vat_1' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='quantity' name="quantity[]" id='quantity_1' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='amount' name="amount[]" id='amount_1' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='total'  name="total[]" id='total_1' ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type='button' value='Add fields' id='addmore' class="btn btn-success">
<input type='button' value='remove' id='remove' class="btn btn-danger">
```

Here is the screenshot for the interface.

[image]

And this is  JS code for adding new row

```
$('#addmore').click(function(){
    var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
    var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');
    var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;
    var html = "<tr class='tr_input'><td><input type='text' name='partnumber[]' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' placeholder='بگه‌ری بۆ پارت نه‌مبه‌ر '></td><td><input type='text' class='name' name='name[]' id='name_"+index+"'></td><td><input type='text' class='price' name='price[]'  id='price_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='vat' name='vat[]' id='vat"+index+"'></td><td><input type='text' class='quantity' name='quantity[]' id='quantity_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='amount' name='amount[]' id='amount_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='total' name='total[]' id='total_"+index+"' ></td><td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td></tr>";

    // Append data
    $('tbody').append(html);
});
```

and finally this is code for calculation the total, only working for the first row.

```
$('.total').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click',function (ev) {
        // var  total=0;
        var quantity=$(this).attr('id');
        var splitid = quantity.split('_');
        var index = splitid[1];
        var price= parseFloat($('#price_'+index).val());
        var vat=parseFloat($('#vat_'+index).val());
        var quan=parseFloat($('#quantity_'+index).val());
        var amount=$('#amount_'+index).val();
        amount=price+vat;
        $('#amount_'+index).val(amount);
        alert(amount);
        //alert(price);
        var total=amount*quan;
        //var qunatity_num=parseInt(quantity.val());
        $('#total_'+index).val(total);

        //alert(total);
        // $('#total_'+index).val(total);
    });
});
```

please, could you tell me what's is wrong with my code, it's been a week I am trying to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: you have to re-attach the eventhandler ( the `$(this).click..`) _after_ you have added a new row (the `$('tbody').append(html);`), because when you loop through all `.total` elements to set the onclick handler you only have one (which is the first row it's working on).

Comment: Well the question is where you have placed $(this).on('click',function(){}) function. It works on the first row because initially the page loads with that row inside the table and all the other rows are added after the page has loaded, in other means there is no listener to that event in your code. so change $(this).on to $('body').on('click','.total', function(){})

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery's [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function to set eventhandlers also on _future_ elements of a selector

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- There is an underscore missing in the HTML that you add for a new row: `vat` should be `vat_`
- Don't use `$('.total').each(function() {`: it is not necessary to loop. The click handler will work on all matching elements, if you take the next point into account:
- Use event delegation to make sure your click handler also gets called for future cells that have the `total` class:

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.total', function (ev) {
  ```

With that it works.

However it would be better not to use dynamic `id` attributes all and use CSS classes only. With jQuery methods you can easily find out which is the "current" row that was clicked on (`.closest("tr")`) and then to `.find()` the element you need in your formula.

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly. I really appreciated.